# Why can't I buy more storage?

Tags: 11.04, ubuntu-one, cloud, storage

Im trying to buy 2x20G of storage but when I try it says "Sorry something went wrong".

Comment: You need to be more specific for us to understand your problem. How are you trying to buy the storage? What kind of storage is it?

Comment: I was trying to buy storage add-ons on ubuntu one. https://one.ubuntu.com/account/add-storage/

Comment: And yes this is true I just tried buying 3x20G storage and get the same message: "Sorry, there was a problem"

What goes wrong?

Answer (score 8):

We had a bug on our website where buying more than one 20-pack of storage wasn't working. We fixed it, now. Sorry!